# Value of this expression

Tags: quadratics

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $$x^2 + x − 3 = 0$$ find the value of the expression $4\beta^2 − \alpha^3$.

I tried using sum of roots and product of roots formulas but could not get the answer.

Comment: Well, the quadratic formula gives you closed forms for the roots, so you could just compute it.

Comment: I honestly don't see how you could get stuck (mainly since you haven't shown us your work)  What's holding you back from computing the roots directly, for example?

Comment: Please add your attempts, even if you got stuck in them, for each approach you state you tried using.

Comment: Your question is incomplete;  please add the attempts you've claimed (actual workings, not claims).  And Hmmm, have you tried using the quadratic equation?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\beta^2=3-\beta\\4\beta^2=12-4\beta$$ 
Also $$\alpha^2=3-\alpha\\\alpha^3=3\alpha-\alpha^2=3\alpha-3+\alpha=4\alpha-3$$
Thus, $$4\beta^2-\alpha^3=15-4(\alpha+\beta)=15+4=19$$